# Angular Controller Parent/Child scope set parent variable to child scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an issue setting a title on my app to correspond to the current state the app is in. I am using $stateprovider and have an abstract parent state that I want to set a title on from its current nested state. The first time I switch states, the title will switch to the correct title. However, when I switch back, the title will no longer change.

My stateprovider looks like this, with the 'tab' state being the state in which the other states are nested within:

```
$stateProvider.

.state('tab', {
    url : "/tab",
    abstract : true,
    templateUrl : "templates/tabs.html",
    controller : function($scope){
        $scope.header = $scope.header || {title: 'Default'};
    }
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:

.state('tab.charts', {
    url : '/charts',
    views : {
        'charts-screen' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/chart.html',
            controller : 'ChartController'
        }
    },
    reload: true
})

.state('tab.report-list', {
    url : '/reportList',
    views : {
        'report-list' : {
            templateUrl : 'templates/tab-report-list.html',
            controller : 'ReportListController'
        }
    }
})
```

I want each nested state to be able to set the header title, like so:

```
.controller('ChartController', function($scope){
    $scope.header.title = 'Chart Title'; 
}

.controller('ReportListController', function($scope){
   $scope.header.title = 'Report Title';
}
```

When I navigate from tab.charts to tab.report-list, the title changes
to the correct title, 'Report Title', but when I navigate back the title
remains the 'Report Title'.

What is the correct way to do this in angular? I thought setting the reload
field of the state would ensure that it re-fetches the $scope variables
in the active controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick is to use `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` this will reload the abstract controller where you can set the title based on the data set for each route. Also adding the heading to `$scope` with-out using data will work with reload at the `ui-sref` link.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tns2qu96/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
 .controller('ChartController', ChartController)
 .controller('ReportListController', ReportListController)
 .config(Config);

function Config($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('tab/charts');
    $stateProvider
     .state('tab', {
        url : "/tab",
        abstract : true,
        templateUrl : "templates/tabs.html",
        controller : function($scope, $state){
            console.log('tabs', $state.current.data.heading);
            $scope.heading = $state.current.data.heading || 'Default';
            //$scope.header = $scope.header || {title: 'Default'};
        }
    })

    // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

    .state('tab.charts', {
        url : '/charts',
        data: {
         heading: 'Charts'
        },
        views : {
            'charts-screen' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/chart.html',
                controller : 'ChartController'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('tab.report-list', {
        url : '/report-list',
        data: {
         heading: 'List'
        },
        views : {
            'report-list' : {
                templateUrl : 'templates/tab-report-list.html',
                controller : 'ReportListController'
            }
        }
    });
    
}

function ReportListController($scope, $state) {
    console.log('reportlist', $state);
}

function ChartController($scope, $state) {
 console.log('chart', $state);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/tabs.html">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
                </div>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" ui-sref="tab.charts" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Charts</a></li>
                      <li>
                          <a href="#" ui-sref="tab.report-list" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">List</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div ui-view=""></div>
            <div ui-view="charts-screen"></div>
            <div ui-view="report-list"></div>
        </div>
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/chart.html">
        <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
        <div ui-view=""></div>
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/tab-report-list.html">
        <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
        <div ui-view=""></div>
    </script>
    
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```